# How to make css width work in firefox

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser, width, alignment

I'm creating an web system, but it's not showing correctly in firefox (and probably not in IE too), but it's great in Google Chrome, the page is that: [Page with errors](http://deva.ipvalverde.com)

The problem is that my ***< ul>*** component is too large in Firefox. I'm using ***width: 760px;*** and repeating an small width image over this 760 pixels. But the firefox do it for more than 760 pixels (as you can see in the link).

This is my ul-html code:

```
<body id="maincontent">
    <ul class="ulmenu">
        <li><a href="#" >Registrar</a></li>
        <li><a id="lastmenu" href="#" >Realizar login</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

And my css:

```
root { 
    display: block;
}
#maincontent
{
    background-color: black;
    width: 760px;
    margin: auto;
}
ul.ulmenu
{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:0;
    display:table;

    width: 760px;
    max-width: 760px;
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 60px;

    background-image: url(../image/menubg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    /*
    visibility: hidden;*/
}
ul.ulmenu li
{
    float: left;
}
ul.ulmenu a
{
    background-image: url(../image/menudiv.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    padding-right: 32px;
    padding-left: 32px;
    line-height: 60px;
    display: block;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 21px;
}
ul.ulmenu a:hover
{
    color: #AAAAAA;
}
```

In order to make the options of the menu centralized, i created some code in JS with jQuery to do that. If I remove this code, the width of green image in firefox becomes smaller, but it's still bigger than necessary (about 100px), the chrome images keeps unchanged.

I know only basics of css. Can anybody point me how can I fix that?

----EDITED-----

Fiddler URL for code (but the error is only noticed on maximized browser):

[See it on Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/ipvalverde/EJGN9/3/)

Comment: Could you set up a JSFiddle example?

Comment: Interesting this JSFiddle.... I'll do that in a minute

Comment: Thanks. It's a lot easier to work with and you'll get more help if you include one.

Comment: Do the li elements need to be floated? Also, I don't see any background in your ul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I understand.

Seems, In firefox your are adding `padding-left` to your element style which makes it wider.

```
ul.ulmenu li
{
    float: left; //remove it
    display: inline-block; // add it
}
```

Remove this line from js code.

```
$(".ulmenu").css("padding-left",Math.round((larTela-menuWidth)/2)+"px");
```

Comment: Thankyou for your reply man! But the other one was more accurate.

Comment: You're welcome if you solved your issue. But I have to say that, 209px is your computed width with javascript. `$(".ulmenu").css("padding-left",Math.round((larTela-menuWidth)/2)+"px");` If you add another li item or change list items width, 551px will not be valid anymore.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, I'll have to set that with javascript too.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:** Give `width: 551px` and `display: block` to your `ul.ulmenu` CSS class. That will solve the issue.

**Reason:** The reason for the issue is FF and Chrome treating `display: table` differently. For an element with `display` set to `table`, FF adds the `padding` to the width, whereas Chrome doesn't. The solution is to use the `display: block` CSS property that behaves the same in both browsers (FF as well as Chrome adds `padding` to the width for `block` elements)

Comment: Amazing! But why change the width to 551px ?

Comment: So that `width` (i.e. 551px) and `padding-left` (i.e. 209px) together gives you the desired visible width which is 760px.